# React. Wrap part of text in span based on multiple string arrays

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First time asking a question on stack overflow, so if I'm not formatiing right or providing enough info let me know.
I am currently using React with Typescript and I need to wrap a parts of a string into spans based on multiple string arrays.

I have this interface for the props/state:

```js
interface TextHIghlighter{
    text: string,
    highlight: {
        targetStrings: string[]
        color: string
    }[]
}
```

I need to loop through all of the highlights and for each string in its targetStrings wrap that part of text in a span with a background color of the highlight's color.

Ie.

When passed in these properties

```
{
    "text": "This is a test string",
    "highlight": [
         {
             "targetStrings": ["This", "test" ]
             "color": "blue"
         },
         {
             "targetStrings": [ "string" ]
             "color": "green"
         }
     ]
}
```

It will render something like

```
<p><span style="background: blue">This</span> <span style="background: green">is</span> a test <span style="background: green">string</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You'll get a little more help if you show how you've attempted to solve the problem so far. Then we can help fill in the gap from where you are now to where you need to be. So when you attempted to solve this, what did that code look like? How did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your display and data structure, you could do

```js
const obj =   {
  "text": "This is a test string",
  "highlight": [
    {
        "targetStrings": ["This", "test" ],
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "targetStrings": [ "string" ],
        "color": "green"
    }
  ]
}

const coloredWords = obj.text.split(" ").map(word => {
  const color = obj.highlight.reduce((acc, item) => {
      const index = item.targetStrings.indexOf(word)
      if (index >= 0) return item.color
      return acc
  }, '')
  return { word, color }
})    


const Example = () => (
  <p>
    {coloredWords.map(item => (
      <span
         key={item.word}
         style={{
           "background": item.color,
           "margin": "0.1rem"
         }}
      >
        {item.word}
      </span>
    ))}
  </p>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```